# Is this the correct interpretation of $\sup_{a \in A} \inf_{b \in B} f(a, b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, order-theory

Suppose $f:A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to understand the notation $$\sup_{a \in A} \inf_{b \in B} f(a, b)$$
My interpretation is this: 
$$\inf_{b \in B} f(a, b) = \{\inf_{b \in B}f(a, b)|a \in A \}$$
That is, $\inf_{b \in B}$ applied to a two or more variable function is a **set**.

Of course, once we have a set, there can only be one interpretation:
$$\sup_{a \in A} \inf_{b \in B} f(a, b)= \sup \{\inf_{b \in B}f(a, b)|a \in A \}.$$ 
I would understand the meaning if $\inf$ was applied to a one variable function. But when it's applied to a two variable function, I find the situation confusing.

Is the above the correct interpretation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

For fixed $a \in A$, the infimum $\inf_{b \in B} f(a,b)$ is a real number, or possibly $-\infty$. This means we may define a function $g: A \to \overline {\mathbb R}$ by
$$g(a) = \inf_{b \in B}f(a,b), \quad \text{for all } a \in A.$$
Then $\sup_{a \in A}\inf_{b \in B} f(a,b)$ is the supremum of $g$ over $A$, i.e.
$$\sup_{a \in A}\inf_{b \in B} f(a,b)= \sup_{a \in A} g(a).$$
So think of $\inf_{b \in B}f(a,b)$ as a function of $a$, and then take the supremum of this function.

Comment: Ah thanks! Is my interpretation of $\inf_{b \in B} f(a, b)$ as the set $\{\inf_{b \in B} f(a, b) |a \in A\}$ correct as well? I was going to say that after all, we take the sup of it, and the sup is technically defined for sets, not functions. But I guess we've given up that notion already.

Comment: No, your interpretation does not make much sense. Sticking with the definition of the function $g(a) = \inf_{b \in B} f(a,b)$, you are asking if $g(a)$ is a set, which of course it isn't. But when we take the supremum of $g$ over $A$, this is indeed defined as the supremum of the set $\{g(a) \mid a \in A\}$, which is the image of $A$ under $g$. So $\sup_{a \in A}g(a)$ is just another notation for $\sup\{g(a) \mid a \in A\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to determine why my interpretation is wrong. My interpretation is: $\inf_{b \in B} f(a, b) = $ the set of all numbers $\inf_{b \in B} f(a_0, b)$, where $a_0$ ranges through $A$. I think this sounds reasonable, and I just tried to put it in more formal set notation.

Comment: What you are describing is the image of $\inf_{b \in B} f(a,b)$ under $A$. By itself, the expression $\inf_{b \in B}f(a,b)$ only makes sense for a particular $a \in A$. To make explicit the set over which we are taking the infimum, we may write $\inf_{b \in B}f(a,b) = \inf\{ f(a,b) \mid b \in B\}.$ Do you see how this is a function depending on $A$?

Answer (score 0):

If we generalize the @averagemonkey's answer, the theme is: In a string of sup's and inf's as you go to the right freeze every variable you pass by, then compute the last sup or inf thus eliminating one of the variables, then work backwards as you successively  compute a sup or inf at a time and get rid of one more variable. Hope this helps.